# SVG Marker Id não sendo "encontrado"

Tags: html, div, svg, id

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho uma lista de web block. Esse web block contém divs cada uma com o código abaixo, que exibo de acordo com o Id enviado.

Esses são os códigos que tenho em cada div:

## Div1

```
"<svg width='200' height='176'>
  <defs>
    <marker id='arrowThree' markerWidth='10' markerHeight='10' refX='0' refY='3' orient='auto' markerUnits='strokeWidth'>
      <path d='M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z' fill='#000' />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line x1='185' y1='5' x2='185' y2='140' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrowThree)' />
  <line x1='178' y1='160' x2='27' y2='25' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrowThree)' />
  <line x1='10' y1='20' x2='10' y2='140' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrowThree)' />
</svg>"
```

## Div2

```
"<svg width='200' height='118'>
  <defs>
    <marker id='arrowTwo' markerWidth='10' markerHeight='10' refX='0' refY='3' orient='auto' markerUnits='strokeWidth'>
      <path d='M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z' fill='#000' />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line x1='185' y1='5' x2='185' y2='82' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrowTwo)' /> 
  <line x1='182' y1='110' x2='27' y2='18' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrowTwo)' />
  <line x1='10' y1='15' x2='10' y2='82' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrowTwo)' />
</svg>"
```

## DIV3

```
"<svg width='200' height='60' id='teste'>
  <defs id='teste1'>
    <marker id='arrowLeftDown' markerWidth='10' markerHeight='10' refX='0' refY='3' orient='auto' markerUnits='strokeWidth'>
      <path d='M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z' fill='#000' />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line x1='10' y1='5' x2='10' y2='25' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrowLeftDown)' />
</svg>"
```

A lista sempre terá div1 ou div2 mais div3.

Ex:

Div1
Div1
Div3
Div3
Div3
Div3

Ou

Div2
Div3
Div3
Div3

O problema é que a div3 não reconhece o marker "arrowLeftDown", mas se eu colocar "arrowThree" se é após Div1 ou "arrowTwo"se após Div2 ele reconhece e coloca o marker. Mas não posso ter essa distinção pois é dinâmico e não quero criar diversas Div3, uma para cada Div1 e Div2.

Comment: Seus svg são arquivos img.svg que vc chama no documento, ou vc usa diretamente o código svg dentro do documento?

Comment: Dentro do documento

Comment: Cara aqui ficou assim http://prntscr.com/od4b5l teria como vc editar e incluir o CSS da div que esse svg vai dentro. Aproveite e inclua tb na pergunta um exemplo completo do HTML inteiro de quando o problema acontece, pq aqui não consegui simular seu problema...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloquei uma tag SVG com o defs antes das demais, então ficou assim:

```
<svg width='0' height='0'>
      <defs>
        <marker id='arrow' markerWidth='10' markerHeight='10' refX='0' refY='3' orient='auto' markerUnits='strokeWidth'>
          <path d='M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z' fill='#000' />
        </marker>
      </defs>
</svg>

<div>
    <svg width='200' height='176'>
      <line x1='185' y1='5' x2='185' y2='140' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrow)' />
      <line x1='178' y1='160' x2='27' y2='25' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrow)' />
      <line x1='10' y1='20' x2='10' y2='140' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrow)' />
    </svg>
</div>

<div>
    <svg width='200' height='118'>  
      <line x1='185' y1='5' x2='185' y2='82' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrow)' /> 
      <line x1='182' y1='110' x2='27' y2='18' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrow)' />
      <line x1='10' y1='15' x2='10' y2='82' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrow)' />
    </svg>
</div>

<div>
    <svg width='200' height='60'> 
      <line x1='10' y1='5' x2='10' y2='25' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrow)' />
    </svg>
</div>
```